# What music plays in Hunter x Hunter SLOW MO?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

2011 release of Hunter x Hunter (Chimera Ants arc):

In the episode where Gon and his friends enter the castle of ants through the hole made by Knov , everything goes like a slow mo and an epic music hits. I apologise for not mentioning the episode number. This music is repeated several times during the arc after the inception.

I have listened to various OST's from Hunter x Hunter but I don't think any of them are the one which I am looking for...

Can someone Identify the music that was playing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay after quite a bit of research, I think I may have found some stuff that may help you.

The episode that you are looking for is [Monster x And x Monster](http://www.crunchyroll.com/hunter-x-hunter/episode-112-monster-x-and-x-monster-646069) (ep. 112). The slow motion part is largely the first half of the episode.

There are a number of tracks that play during the slow motion scenes. [Here's](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL_3rJhzHvq5GJ_FATfhk4_lUNIs9zBuxR) a playlist of tracks from the Chimera Ant arc (30 tracks), of which I think your best bets are either [Hegemony of the Food Chain](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDTGFaC9SZA&index=30&list=PL_3rJhzHvq5GJ_FATfhk4_lUNIs9zBuxR), [Kingdom of Predators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q43wzP6A1CM&index=29&list=PL_3rJhzHvq5GJ_FATfhk4_lUNIs9zBuxR), or [Legend of the Martial Artist](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WYS1PjTkHIQ&index=14&list=PL_3rJhzHvq5GJ_FATfhk4_lUNIs9zBuxR). Of the three, I think Legend of the Martial Artist is the song you are referring to, but you can go through the playlist to find the specific song for which you are looking. Keep in mind that multiple tracks were playing during the time you are referring, so it might be a mix of a few different songs in that playlist.

Comment: It was legend of the Martial Artist I shazamed it

Comment: @NirmalRaj one of my personal favorites, and one of the best tracks of the whole anime